# Is it possible building a web spider with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, electron, whatsapp

I'm building a Whatsapp bot using Electron. I'm using Whatsapp Web and tying to parse HTML codes.

Electron is a "programmable chromium" so it is perfect to write web bot in theory.
I was using web browser component of C# and it was extremely powerful but it uses old version of Internet Explorer as engine.

---

1- )  I tried using `webview` kit but I cant get any HTML code from it.

```
<webview id="webview" preload="./inject.js"  src="https://web.whatsapp.com" style="display:inline-flex; width:100%; height:800px"  ></webview>
```

In inject.js file there is some js code can be run but it is not usefull for me.

---

2-)  I tried loading website directly and it loaded without any trobble. But I cant reach html codes easly and cant trigger js events.

```
win.loadURL('https://web.whatsapp.com', {
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.52 Safari/537.36'
        });
```

I tried to use ipc to carry HTML codes to `nodejs` side(main thread) but it is not efficient also. It freezes when returning a DOM that selected by class or id. Electron window not freezing but program stops talking via `ipc`.

My ipc code;

```
const electron = require('electron')
var ipc = electron.ipcMain      
var jstext = '(function(){ if(document.getElementById("pane-side"))  var el = document.getElementById("pane-side").children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0];  if(el) {el.onclick.apply(el)}  }) () '
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript("require('electron').ipcRenderer.send('gpu', "+jstext+");");
    ipc.on('gpu', (_, gpu) => {
        console.log("gpu: ",gpu)
        setTimeout(requestFromwwin, 500)    
    })
```

---

So I could not to do anything. 
It is possible developing a web bot with Electron? Is there any tutorial for it that showing best-practice?

Comment: try this http://nightwatchjs.org

Comment: If you wanna listen to the event (message) using this approach it could be painful, it possible. The best approach is using IPC as you already tried

Comment: Here is the guy who use electron as crawler but he using simle crawler https://github.com/cfpb/cfgov-crawler-app